# Audio shuttering after down and upsampling

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api, resampling

I try to sample my mic audio down and up again (for transfer). But after the process the audio is a bit broken (shuttering). You can try it yourself if you have a mic:

**FIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/q4yjfxqv/10/ (updated 21.07.16)

You hear the shuttering more on higher frequences.

I downsample by just removing half of the array

```
function newDownSample(data) {
  var retBuffer = [];
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
    if(i%2==0)
    retBuffer.push(data[i])
  }
  return retBuffer;
};
```

And upsample (liniar)

```
function newUpSample(data) {
  var retBuffer = [];
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
    retBuffer.push(data[i])
    if(i<data.length-1)
      retBuffer.push((data[i]+data[i+1])/2);
    else
        retBuffer.push(data[i]);
  }
  return retBuffer;
};
```

I tried other interpolation methods like liniar, cubic and lanczos form [here](https://github.com/osuushi/Smooth.js/) as well... with the same shutter effect.

The shutter is always happen on the edge off the chunk. You can hear this by chaning the chunk size from 1024 to 4096 at the example (it will happen less).

But why? Anyone can exmplain this and how to solve ?

Any hint is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code for interpolation is, that you don't know the first sample of the next block and therefore cannot properly interpolate the last sample of the current one.

To get around this you need to save the last sample from one block to calculate the first interpolated sample for the next block.

[https://jsfiddle.net/hhb240ms/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/hhb240ms/2/)

```
usSample[0] = (lastSample + data[0]) / 2;
usSample[1] = data[0];
for(var i=1;i<512;i++) {
  usSample[2*i] = (data[i] + data[i-1]) / 2;
  usSample[2*i+1] = data[i]
}
lastSample = data[data.length-1];
```

Comment: very nice :) I like!

Answer (score 0):

Im not an expert about audio programming.

What I try when I got weird results (with general programming problems) is changing the parameters of the algorithm and bring it back to the basics.

What happens when you dont downsample ?.

Audio is very sensitive to even the smallest errors.
What if the buffer isnt big enough or when (using the main thread) processing blocks playing sounds.

Are you doing any other processing other than modulating on this thread ?
What about a different (HTML5) browser ?
Currently I cant think of any other solution or hints.

Good luck, I hope this helps.
Please post the solution, this will help other programmers aswell.

Comment: hey, thanks for the respones... I tried a lot so far. you can toggle resample at the fiddle and check that without its working well. Firefox and chrome are broken (at least)... I will test more computers tomorrow.

Comment: Try this ..https://jsfiddle.net/ck3sgan9/9/

is upscaling necessary ?
Because you will always lose quality, This is a work around (not upsampling) but it works. and I dont hear heavy audio quality loss.

This fidle only uses downsampling.

Comment: WoW thanks. I dont know how this is possible... its better to use the same value twice than to interpolate?

Comment: Unless your original signal is already bandlimited, down sampling without filtering always produces artifacts.  If you can't hear it, it means the original source was bandlimited enough that you can't hear it.

Comment: do you mean downsampled and bitrated by "bandlimited"? thats true but its 48k samplerate and 32Bit (float). What filters could remove this ?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the OS and machine you are running on, you may want to increase the buffer size specified in creatScriptProcessor.  With the size you have, I hear artifacts, but when I increase the size to 16384, I no longer hear the artifacts.  (But now I get a pretty long latency before I hear anything, as expected from the large buffer size).

Comment: If I change chunk size, only the duration between the shuts spread

Answer (score 0):

When i = (data.length-1), you're going to get a null for data[i+1] - so the upsampling will probably be averaging the last sample with zero?

(This isn't great downsampling - since it doesn't bandwidth-contrain first - but I expect you knew that.)

Comment: yeah I already found this data.length-1 error but is still shuttering. I removed bandwidth-contrain for this example because it isnt its fault

Comment: Really?  I don't hear any audio issues in the revised fiddle on my macbook or desktop.  Maybe it's due to the machine you're running it on not being able to keep up with the audioprocess events? (Though I'd think that was odd.)  Your dynamic allocation and array.push() is likely inefficient; I wrote a hardcoded version at https://jsfiddle.net/12ubug1o/.  See if it exhibits the same behavior.

Comment: Also, you might want to disable echo cancellation - a la https://jsfiddle.net/12ubug1o/1/.

Comment: thanks echo cancellation off didnt help me. I hear it most on high freq can u test with the oscillator I build in? https://jsfiddle.net/12ubug1o/3/ you got no shutter?

Comment: I don't hear stuttering.  I hear some very definite noise, but it sounds like interference with the upsampling/downsampling not smoothing across onaudioprocess boundaries, maybe?